# Defining affine subspace by a solution to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If I'm given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}$ and nonzero vector $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, what is the dimension of the affine subspace corresponding to the solutions to $A \vec{x} = b$?

---

My first thought:

There is a case where this has no solution, but let's ignore that one. Assume that there is at least one solution $\vec{x}_0$.

Hence, our solutions are $\vec{x}_0 + null(A)$. This is an affine subspace of dimension $n - rank(A)$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

My concern though is when I say $\vec{x}_0 + null(A)$ contains all solutions to $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$. So I tried to prove this.

Lemma:

Let $\vec{x}_1$ be a vector that solves $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$, but is not in $\vec{x}_0 + null(A)$.

Here I get stuck, I want to derive a contradiction somehow. I can easily derive a contradiction for when $A$ is full rank, but I don't know how to do the case for when $A$ is not full rank.

Comment: Related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315548/affine-subspace-of-bbbr27?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $S$ and $S_0$ the sets of the solutions of equations $Ax=b$ and $Ax=0$ respectively. If the first equation is compatible, let $x_0$ be any fixed solution. Then we have

$$ S = S_0+x_0 \tag{*}$$

so that

$$ \dim_{\text{aff}}(S) := \dim_{\text{vec}}(S_0) = m-\text{rank}(A)\,. $$

The proof of $\;(^*)$ is very simple:
\begin{align}
 x\in S_0+x_0 &\implies x=z+x_0\;\;[\text{for some }z\in S_0]\\[1.5ex]
&\implies Ax=A(z+x_0) = Az + Ax_0 = 0+b =b \implies x\in S
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
x\in S &\implies A(x-x_0) = Ab-Ab = 0\\[1.5ex]
&\implies x-x_0\in S_0 \implies x\in S_0+x_0\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense

Comment: Glad to have been helpful.